# Is it possible and normal to use the words without any verbs in everyday English? (look at the example)

Tags: grammar, spoken-english

1. Is it possible and normal to use the words without any verbs in this particular example?(The highlighted part I mean)
2. Are we allowed to add an irrevelant sentence in the middle of it? ( the added sentence is in parentheses )

> This story and also these kinds of stories are usually about money & marriage. **The story of envy, jealousy, comparing your life with your friends' lives and in this particular case ( I know this is gonna sound weird ) the story of being the wife and, moreover, the main breadwinner of the family.**

Comment: Why do you think the part in parentheses is irrelevant?

Comment: I find this question as confusing now as I did before. You're asking two different things—and *comparing* is a verb. Yes, you *can* have sentences without verbs. But are you asking us to proofread this particular one?

Comment: Also, did you delete your previous question and then just ask it again? Because I commented on a version of this earlier today—well before it looks like this one was created.

Comment: @JasonBassford hey, folks, the way I see it my question is crystal clear and I just cannot get through to what exactly do you mean? I want to know this way of speaking **is** usual and customary or **not**. If I am not allowed to ask this type of question, well, just tell me and believe I'd never ask again...

Answer (score 1):

In journalese and literature writers sometimes get creative with structure and use sentence fragments without a verb rather than standard sentences with a predicate. [Once the context is clear it's perfectly acceptable](https://www.quora.com/Can-there-be-a-complete-sentence-without-a-noun-or-verb-If-yes-what-are-some-examples).

In your example I think the context is pretty clear and works, though personally -- subjectively -- I'd prefer if it were turned into a standard sentence using a colon or dash after marriage.

> This story and also these kinds of stories are usually about money &
>   marriage -- the story of envy, jealousy, comparing your life with your
>   friends' lives and in this particular case ( I know this is gonna
>   sound weird ) the story of being the wife and, moreover, the main
>   breadwinner of the family.

As for the 'irrelevant sentence' in parentheses, I think it's irrelevancy is subjective. I imagine the author found it important or they wouldn't have used it. In any case it's grammatically correct.